# How to create database automatically using xml files which contains schema and data?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, oracle11g

creating any database (oralce sql database or mysql database)

I have huge XML files which form a complete database, and I need to create a database using those XML files?
each XML file contains its schema and data needed.
each XML file form as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
<!--
- Structure schemas
-->
<pma:structure_schemas>
    <pma:database name="wiki" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
        <pma:table name="article">
            CREATE TABLE `article` (
              `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
              `title` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
              KEY `title` (`title`(32))
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=binary;
        </pma:table>
    </pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas>

<!--
- Database: 'wiki'
-->
<database name="wiki">
    <!-- Table article -->
    <table name="article">
        <column name="id">12</column>
        <column name="title">Anarchism</column>
    </table>
    <table name="article">
        <column name="id">25</column>
        <column name="title">Autism</column>
    </table>
    <table name="article">
        <column name="id">39</column>
        <column name="title">Albedo</column>
    </table>
</database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

So, how can I use those files to build the database ?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Also, Is there a way for creating database using XML files or to import XML files in a database using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: This looks like a file generated by by phpadmin. Why don't you use phpadmin to create the new database?

Comment: It is a combined work, so there are another scripts which generate these needed XML files.

Comment: My database tool of choice is liquibase (See: http://www.liquibase.org/) Google around you'll find other similar tools. In all cases you are better off imitating their XML formats rather than inventing your own.

Answer (score 0):

The somewhat simple answer is:

- parse the XML file (`SimpleXml`, `DOM`)
- create database(s) and table(s) with (`mysqli` or `PDO`)

alternatively, if you have control over the creation of the XML-structure:

- mimick `phpmyadmin's` format and use `phpmyadmin` (or any other tool) to do the job.